composite rule and Richardson extrapolation
a)Using the composite midpoint rule,compute the approximate value for the integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}dx$, using the mesh size(length of subintervals) of $h=0.5$ and $h=1$.
b)Derive the Richardson extrapolation formulation for the composite midpoint rule $M(h)$ assuming that it can be written as $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=M(h)+K_{1}h^{2}+K_{2}h^{4}\ldots$ where $K_{i}$`s are independent of $h$.
c)Based on the approximate values computed in part(a), use Richardson extrapolation to compute a more accurate approximation to the integral.
d)Is the extrapolated result computed in part(c) exact in this case?
My attempt:
As first step I wrote the midpoint rule as $\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}f(x)dx\approx f(\frac{x_{i+1}+x_{i}}{2})(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$. Moreover the error is if you write $\bar{h}=\frac{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}{2}$ then the error in the approximation is $\frac{\bar{h}^{3}}{3}f''(\epsilon)$ and moreover to approximate $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}f(x)dx$ where $a=x_{0}<x_{1}<\ldots< x_{n}$ and here $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$. Then the error is somethying like $\frac{(b-a)f''(\epsilon)h^{2}}{24}$.But my main concern is I really can not understand what part $c)$ says.Richardson extrapolation is a differentiation rule. It is something like $f(x+h)-f(x-h)=2hf'(x)+\frac{2}{6}h^{3}f'''(x)+\frac{2}{5!}h^{5}f^{5}(x)\ldots$. How does this rule related to the integration? If I solve this I will solvev most of the question?I will be pleased if you help as much as you can because this question is demanding for me
Thank you in advance

Richardson extrapolation is the idea that if you have some approximation depending on a step size parameter that reads as
$$
A(h)=A_{exact}+A_ph^p+...,
$$
then you can eliminate the leading error term and get a better approximation by combining two approximations $A(h_1)$ and $A(h_2)$, $h_1\ne h_2$. This can be applied to differentiation, but also to quadrature. Systematic application to the quadrature case is also known as Romberg integration.

The elimination is as simple as
$$
h_1^pA(h_2)-h_2^pA(h_1)=(h_1^p-h_2^p)A_{exact}+0\cdot A_p+h_1^ph_2^p(h_2^{q-p}-h_1^{q-p})A_q+...
$$
if $q$ is the next degree after the leading term in the error expansion.

I did not understand the concept I am sorry. Should I apply it again to the composite midpoint rule?In how many times in part c?

In c) you apply the formula of b) with the values from a). In b) you solve the abstract elimination problem for $K_1$ based on $h_1=h$, $h_2=/2$. In d) you compare the order of the remaining error with the degree of the input polynomial.

After solving K1 until where I should solve. Can I decide Kj for arbitrary j in Richardson extrapolation formula in part b)? How will I derive all the K2,K3,K4 until a large KL?. Moreover more accurate approximation in part c) is very unclear? Until where I should go?

Richardson is only one step, only the elimination of the one lowest order error term. A process to eliminate further terms is Romberg, which is not asked for here.

Should I find only K1 and K2 then?
